# Multiple UART devices on Raspberry Pi

Tags: raspberry-pi, uart, serial

I want to connect multiple devices which are communicating through UART to Rapsberry Pi3b+. Given that Raspberry has only 1 set of Tx-Rx pins, I am unable to do so. I am designing a PCB so I have the scope to add additional components. One way to do so would have been a UART to I2C bridge but most solutions are expensive and the choice of ICs is very limited (NXP was one).

Edit : They need to communicate every 500 milliseconds and in parallel.

Comment: Do they need them to communicate in parallel.. can you talk to them one after the other?

Comment: No, they have to talk to in parallel and in high frequency, i.e 1 every 500 milliseconds.

Comment: A UART channel can be bit-banged. May not be fun on a Pi but possible.

Comment: Also, 500 milliseconds is super slow. A UART channel at 115200baud can move 5700 messages in that time. That would be 8 bits of data, one start bit, and one stop bit. What can't be accomplished with 5700 messages?

Comment: What do you mean by "multiple"? Two? Twenty?

Comment: How much data does each channel transfer each 500ms? One byte? That's almost nothing.

Answer (score 1):

One solution would be to use USB-UART chips. They are not expensive and typically require only a few capacitors and an inexpensive crystal.

For example, the FTDI FT232RL or the [CH340](https://cdn.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Dev/Arduino/Other/CH340DS1.PDF).